# Dojox charting legend image rotation

Tags: charts, dojo

Is there a way to rotate an image symbol in the legend widget??

I'm using a few vertical lines in my graph to show the location
of a leak on a chart.  The legend shows these lines as horizontal
which is fine but, it would be better to rotate it and show
a vertical line. That would be wayyyy more intuitive to the user.

Thx!!

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it is not supported.